# MetaMask - RPC Error: [ethjs-query] while formatting outputs from RPC

Tags: solidity, truffle, blockchain, react

I am new to blockchain. I am trying to create an app using truffle react box but getting this exception when I tried to call the "increment" function.
This might be a really foolish mistake but please help me out with this one..

This is the exception I got:

[image]

below is the part of my app.js where I am getting the error. I have added a comment to the part which returned the exception.

runExample = async () => {
const { accounts, contract } = this.state;

```
// Stores a given value, 5 by default.
await console.log(accounts[0]);
await contract.methods.set(55).send({ from: accounts[0] });

// Get the value from the contract to prove it worked.
const response = await contract.methods.get().call();

// Update state with the result.
this.setState({ storageValue: response });


//this part is giving the error
await contract.methods.increment().send({ from: accounts[0] });
const ctr = await contract.methods.display().call();
this.setState({ ctrVal: ctr });
```

};

Here is my smart contract:

// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity >=0.4.21 <8.10.0;

contract SimpleStorage {
uint256 storedData;
uint256 ctr = 0;

```
function set(uint256 x) public {
    storedData = x;
}

function get() public view returns (uint256) {
    return storedData;
}

function increment() public {
    ctr = ctr + 1;
}

function display() public view returns (uint256) {
    return ctr;
}
```

}